# How to accessing admin local data location from non-admin user?

Tags: c#

I have an installer that will run as adminstrator. On installing that exe in non-admin system account, some files shipped in administrator local appdata location. I need to access admin local appdata location (C:\Users{ admin user name}\AppData\Local) using process in console app that is in non-admin account.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\{admin user name}\AppData\Local";
proc.Start();
```

But current user local appdata location opened in file explorer while run. Could you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: But you asked it to open the directory, so yes, file explorer opened.. You didnt ask it to write a file there, or run an exe from it

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code works for me!!!

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe",@"C:\Users\{admin user name}\AppData\Local");
```